# checking ngif for undefined fails

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm doing a check in the template

```
<div *ngIf="product.info && product.info !== undefined">
  <quill-view-html [content]="product.info"></quill-view-html>
</div>
```

And when IDEA starts, it throws an error

```
error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Isn't this check enough?

Comment: I think simple `<div *ngIf="product.info>` will also check for undefined

Comment: you could also check the length `<div *ngIf="product && product.info && product.info.length > 0">` depending on your use case

Comment: try `<div *ngIf="product.info && product.info != undefined">
  <quill-view-html [content]="product.info"></quill-view-html>
</div>`